# Averaging two list of lists

Tags: python, list, average

I have two lists of lists, and I would like to create a new list of list, containing each list average(averaging the values in each spot).
for example: if I have the following lists:

```
 file1 = [[1, -1], [2, -2], [3, -3], [4, -4]]
 file2 = [[20, -40], [2, 0], [-50, 7], [30150, -200]]
```

the average list outcome will be: (using int to round)

```
avg = [[10, -20], [2, -1], [-23, 2], [15077, -102]]
```

once I've done that, if the lists aren't the same length, I must add the components of the long list as is. for example:

```
file1 = [[1, -1], [2, -2], [3, -3], [4, -4],[100, 100]
 file2 = [[20, -40], [2, 0], [-50, 7], [30150, -200]]
```

the outcome will be:

```
[[10, -20], [2, -1], [-23, 2], [15077, -102],[100, 100]]
```

I was thinking of using nested loops but it seems like too much of operations. 
(since these lists are just examples, and I'm using a very long list instead..)
thx for the help!

Comment: I don't understand your numbers. What are you averaging?

Comment: all numbers that are in the same position. 1 and 20, -1 and 40 and so on @cha0site

Comment: They are no averaged in any way I can conceive of

Comment: so how come -1 and -40 average to 10?

Comment: oh sry ! ive added a wrong list. Fixed it.. thanks @roganjosh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to merge our files to then append average of our tuple values to `avg`.

```
file1 = [[1, -1], [2, -2], [3, -3], [4, -4],[100, 100]]
file2 = [[20, -40], [2, 0], [-50, 7], [30150, -200]]
avg = []

for x1, x2 in zip(file1, file2):
    avg.append([(x1[0] + x2[0])//2, (x1[1] + x2[1])//2])

if len(avg) < len(file1):
    avg.extend(file1[len(avg):])
elif len(avg) < len(file2):
    avg.extend(file2[len(avg):])

print(avg) # -> [[10, -21], [2, -1], [-24, 2], [15077, -102], [100, 100]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in one line, you can do something like:

```
>>> [ [ int(sum(l2)/len(l2)) for l2 in zip(*l)] for l in zip(file1, file2) ]
[[10, -20], [2, -1], [-23, 2], [15077, -102]]
```

And we can do ugly things with `zip_longest`, too:

```
>>> [ [ int(sum([x for x in l2 if x is not None])/len([x for x in l2 if x is not None])) for l2 in zip_longest(*l)] for l in zip_longest(file1, file2, fillvalue=[]) ]
[[10, -20], [2, -1], [-23, 2], [15077, -102], [100, 100]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

lst1 = [[1, -1], [2, -2], [3, -3], [4, -4], [100, 100]]
lst2 = [[20, -40], [2, 0], [-50, 7], [30150, -200]]


def avg(numbers):
    not_none = [n for n in numbers if n is not None]
    return sum(not_none) // len(not_none)


result = [[avg(e) for e in zip_longest(il, jl)] for il, jl in zip_longest(lst1, lst2, fillvalue=[])]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[10, -21], [2, -1], [-24, 2], [15077, -102], [100, 100]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good solution:

```
def averageList(list1, list2):
    avg = []
    n = 0
    while n < max(len(list1), len(list2)):
        if n < min(len(list1), len(list2)):
            avg.append([int((list1[n][0]+list2[n][0])/2), int((list1[n][1]+list2[n][1])/2)])
        elif len(list1) > len(list2):
            avg.append(list1[n])
        elif len(list1) < len(list2):
            avg.append(list2[n])
        n = n+1
    return avg
```